# php show two records in a row and then repeat, starting from the middle

Tags: php

I am trying to show a starting order table for speed climbing competition, for multiple categories (children). PHP/Mysql. There are two lanes that are climbed simuntaniously, A and B. Each competitor climbes both lanes. The starting order should be in starting number order for lane A and for lane B in the same order as Lane A with a stagger of 50%, rounding down where there is an odd number of starters.

Sample: Let's say I have a category with 9 competitors, starting numbers from 101 to 109. The output starting order table should be like:

```
  Lane A    Lane B  
   101       105    
   102       106    
   103       107    
   104       108    
   105       109       
   106       101    
   107       102    
   108       103    
   109       104
```

Any ideas? Query or few loops or...
Thanks

Edit:
Query to get table in order Lane A then Lane B:

```
create temporary table laneA
select * from competitors where category = 1 order by stNo;

create temporary table laneB
select * FROM competitors where category = 1 order by (case when stNo > (select avg(stNo) from competitors )then 1 else 2 end), stNo;

select 1 as rank, x.* from laneA as x
union ALL
select 2 as rank, y.* from laneB as y
order by rank;

drop temporary table laneA;
drop temporary table laneB;
```

Comment: I think your question is not really clear. Which have you tried so far? What you can't use a simple `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Order by what? I have made a join query that shows records in order 101÷109 (lane A) and then 105÷109, 101÷104. But how do I show this in html table like in sample? What I think I need is order to be like 101, 105, 102, 106 etc but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What about having an array of competitors for Lane B, removing x number of them from the front of the array and appending the list of those removed to the end of the array?

Comment: Please, include the code of what you have tried, we are here to help, not to do it for you, avoid asking low-effort questions, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Thanks, nice idea. HenriqueHBR- I understand your point but I need ideas, not solutions.

Comment: Put the data in a zero-based array, loop over it. _Calculate_ what index you need to access the corresponding elements to show in the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data in a zero-based array, loop over it. *Calculate* what index you need to access the corresponding elements to show in the second column:

```
$data = range(101, 109); // fake data array, [0 => 101, 1 => 102, ...]
$c = count($data);

for($i=0; $i<$c; ++$i) {
  echo $data[$i] . ' - ' . $data[ ($i + $c / 2) % $c ] . "<br>\n";
}
```

Echo the current element in the first column, and the one with the index set off by half of the count of elements, “clamped down” to the actual index range by modulo of the count again. (With an uneven count, the inner calculation results in a float with .5 at the end, but the modulo operation automatically equalizes that.)

Result:

```
101 - 105
102 - 106
103 - 107
104 - 108
105 - 109
106 - 101
107 - 102
108 - 103
109 - 104
```

And if you add one more, so you have an even number of items, it’ll be

```
101 - 106
102 - 107
103 - 108
104 - 109
105 - 110
106 - 101
107 - 102
108 - 103
109 - 104
110 - 105
```